# What are Plotly's default colour scales?

Tags: plotly

On [this page](https://plot.ly/javascript/heatmaps/) plotly alludes to the fact they have some default colour scales, such as "Viridis". I cannot for the life of my find a web page documenting what these named colour scales are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I'm British and spell colour correctly. The colour scales can be found at https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/color-scales/ and in [this source file](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/colorscale/scales.js) for JavaScript.